# Почему не работает SharedPreferences? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-sdk

```
SharedPreferences spref;
final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    public void savee(View view) {
    spref=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed=spref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, "hih");
    ed.apply();
}
    public void loadd(View view) {
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    spref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    load=spref.getString(SAVED_TEXT,"");
    textView.setText(load);
}
```

В чем ошибка? Должно сохранить слово hih, но когда запускается loadd ничего не выводится.

Comment: Этот код в одной активити находится? Если нет, то это не будет работать

Comment: этого кода недостаточно, чтобы решить вашу проблему. Где находятся эти методы, когда и откуда вызываются?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается ошибка в том что я писал `getPreferences();` , а надо писать `getSharedPreferences()`.